# Direct sum of two Hilbert spaces is a inner product.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, direct-sum

Today I am working with Functional Analysis regarding Hilbert Spaces from the notes. Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be Hilbert Spaces. The direct sum $H_1\oplus H_2$ is the vector spaces $H_1\times H_2$ with the following inner product,

$$\langle (x,y)|(x',y')\rangle:=\langle x|x' \rangle_{H_1}+\langle y|y' \rangle_{H_2} ,$$
where $(x,y),(x',y')\in H_1\times H_2 $.

Well I know the definition of an inner product, i.e. linearity, symmetry, and positive definiteness however I cannot see how to do it with this direct sum. Anyone who can give me a hint or maybe show one of them and then I can try to work the rest out. Thanks in advance.

---

Notice this is NOT homework. It is just me that wants to convince myself that this is a inner product.

---

Edit: I've shown that this indeed defines an inner product. How about norm? Is it true that the norm of $H_1\oplus H_2$ is $ \|\langle x,x'\rangle,\langle y,y'\rangle\|=(\|\langle  x,x' \rangle\|^2+\|\langle y,y' \rangle\|^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Since you know the definition, you verify that this is an inner product by verifying that the definition holds. If you've gotten stuck on doing this, there must be a specific axiom you're having trouble verifying; which one is it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment. I cannot get started and I belive it's the notation. I would like to show i.e. symmetry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space
writing $\langle x,y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$ however the notation in my direct sum is a bit different and thats the reason why I get stuck. 

So, I would like to see how symmetry can be done and then I try with linearity. Make sense?

Comment: Showing that this inner product satisfies symmetry means showing that $\langle (x, y) | (x', y') \rangle = \overline{ \langle (x', y') | (x, y) \rangle }$. Can you do this? (Apply the definition to each side.)

Comment: Okay I hope it makes sense. I edited it a bit. $\langle (x, y) | (x', y') \rangle = \langle x | x' \rangle_{H_1}+\langle y | y' \rangle_{H_2} = \overline{\langle x' | x \rangle}_{H_1} + \overline{\langle y' | y \rangle}_{H_2} =\overline{\langle x' | x \rangle_{H_1}+\langle y' | y \rangle_{H_2}}=\langle\overline{(x', y') | (x, y)}\rangle$ please correct me if I am wrong because this notation is a bit different than what I am used to.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Try the other axioms now!

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try to write them down and then let you know.

Comment: Okay I'm a bit confused now. To show linearity is it then correct that $ \langle (a_1x_1+a_2x_2, y) | (a_1x'_1+a_2x'_2, y')\rangle = a_1\langle (x_1,y)|(x_1',y')\rangle+a_2\langle (x_2,y)|(x_2',y') \rangle$? I used the definition from the link I provided.

Comment: No, that's not what you need to show and it's also not true. Linearity in the first variable means $\langle a_1 (x_1, y_1) + a_2 (x_2, y_2) | (x', y') \rangle = a_1 \langle (x_1, y_1) | (x', y') \rangle + a_2 \langle (x_2, y_2) | (x', y') \rangle$. You need to take a linear combination of two vectors in the direct sum, which here are $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$; you're taking linear combinations in $x$ only.